# Using Clear Seam unwrapped my entire mesh again instead of the face i selected

Tags: uv

I had nearly completed unwrapping my uv map when i accidentally selected mark seams from islands.  Now when i try to go back and remove the seams it completely reworks the entire UV map.

I go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I am hoping someone can provide some guidance to help me remove the unwanted seams.

To help add some clarification, this is how i believe it is supposed to work:

First add some seams and unwrap.
[image]

Next to optimize the mesh add or remove seams:[image]

but the uv stays the same until you unwrap again:
[image]

But if i add or remove a seam even a single seam on my mesh i end up with this:

[image]

Hope that clears things up a bit.

Thanks!

Comment: To remove seams - select them (or select all "A") then press CTRL + "E" > Clear Seam. However it looks like in the first image you used Smart UV Project to unwrap your mesh.

Comment: You are correct, most everything was done with smart project.  At some point I apparently marked a bunch of seams.  When I try to remove them using the methods described in the response it distorts my entire mesh.  I’ve tried to determine if live update is on or something similar but I’m not having much luck.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

[image]

Apparently this option appears in more than one place.  It turns out Live Unwrap **was** enabled in the options menu.  Turned it off and it started behaving like i wanted.  This option does look useful though.  Will have to remember it later if manually unwrapping uv's in the future.

Comment: Apparently this option appears in more than one place. For anyone else that need explicit locations on where those two places are: 1) Workspace: UV Editing/UV Editor/Header/UV/LiveUnwrap: OFF 2) Workspace: UV Editing/3D Viewport/(in Edit Mode)/SideBar("n")/Options/UVsLiveUnwrap: OFF